# How to call a method function from another class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know how to call a method function from another class in Java but unaware about it in Javascript. 
**fileA.js**

```
class A {
     method1(){
          //some code
          method2();
     }
     constructor(){
          //some code
     }
     render(){
          //some code
     }
}
```

**fileB.js**

```
class B{
     method2(){
          //some code
     }
}
```

Also please note that I've included fileA.js and fileB.js in  in index.html.

Also, if you wish to close this question, please let me know the answer for my query because I haven't been able to find a similar question here.

**My take on:-**
I thought of using `class A extends B{ }` but it didn't work.
Then I thought that possibly I can use `import method2 from fileB.js` statement in fileA.js but it failed too.

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hey – What method are you trying to call from where and overall what are you trying to achieve? Some more context would help answer your question effectively

Comment: I thought of using class A extends B{}.. but it didn't work.. Also, tried using import statement in fileA.js but it didn't work either

Comment: What's the relationship between these classes? You could do `(new B).method2()` but is the instance of `B` relevant here? You could just put `method2` to a utility file.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem or even the code that helps to understand your problem

Comment: @Damilare I'm calling method2() from inside fileA.js. method2() is defined in fileB.js

Comment: Why not instantiate B when you need an object of that class? Why not use an instance of B if if already exists? Why not put method2 in the global namespace if that is not related to B?

Comment: Your code is not creating any instances of A nor B. There is not much we can say without seeing how you plan to create instance(s). You should make this question more concrete, so we can understand what your goal is.

Comment: @NehaChaudhary wrote a solution for you somewhere in the thread. When you extend the class, you may have forgotten the `this` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class is nothing more than a generic definition of an object. You cannot call class methods from the classes themselves. You need to instantiate an object from that class, then you would be able to call the class methods on the object.

```js
class B {
  method2() {
    console.log("method2 in objectB called");
  }
}

class A {
  method1() {
    console.log("method1 in objectA called");
    var objB = new B();
    objB.method2();
  }
  constructor() {
    //some code
  }
  render() {
    console.log("render in objectA called");
  }
}

var objectA = new A();
var objectB = new B();

objectA.method1();
objectA.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to instantiate class B, you can access method2 through class B's prototype (alternatively, you can use a static method as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67355333/8086209)), e.g.:

File B.js:

```js
class B{
     method2(){
          //some code
          console.log("B / method 2");
     }
   /* you could also go with a static method:
    static method2() {
          //some code
          console.log("B / method 2");
    }
    */
}
export default B;
```

File A.js:

```js
import B from "./B.js";
class A {
     method1(){
          //some code
          console.log("A / method 1")
          B.prototype.method2();
          /* if you used the "static" approach, then prototype is useless:
          B.method2();
          */ 
     }
     constructor(){
          //some code
     }
     render(){
          //some code
     }
}
export default A;
```

File index.html:

```html
<script type="module">
import A from "./A.js";
let aObject = new A();
aObject.method1();
</script>
```

Will produce the following ouput:

```
A / method 1
B / method 2
```

NB: you will need to run `index.html` from a server. Modules won't work on `file://`

Comment: class A and class B are defined in two different js files. I tried the prototype approach but it doesn't work.

Comment: i have edited my answer to clarify how to use exports/imports & prototype

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call method of class without instantiate it you have to use **static** keyword

> The static keyword defines a static method or property for a class.
> Neither static methods nor static properties can be called on
> instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself.

```
class B{
     static  method2(){
          console.log("B / method 2");
     }
}
class A {
    static method1(){
          //some code
          console.log("A / method 1")
          B.method2();
     }
     constructor(){
          //some code
     }
     render(){
          //some code
     }
}
A.method1();
```

Answer (score -1):

This should solve the issue for you, kindly let me know

```
class A {
  constructor() {

  }

  bro() {
    console.log('bro')
  }
}

class B extends A {
  g() {
    this.bro()
  }
}

new B().g()
```

Here, when B extends A, it gains access to all the methods in A, including `bro`. Calling `this.bro()` is like calling `B.bro` from the class `B` where this is referring to the class itself. Similar to saying something like `self.bro` i.e. the `bro` method in myself which I now how, because I am an extension of `A`.

In this case, I'm assuming that `A` & `B` are related somehow and that the method we are trying to call truly belongs in the class where it was placed.

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Also, what's the reason for randomly extending other classes? What if there is another class C you want to call a method from? Why not write everything in one class if you want to abuse OOP?

Comment: This refers to the object of the scope where it is called. In this case, it refers to the scope of Class B, which now has access to the `bro` method since it inherits from the parent `B`.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Haha, there's no reason to get like that over finding solutions to a problem @NicoHaase, there are nicer ways to relate with people. In this case, I'm assuming that `A` & `B` are related somehow & I'm not over-optimizing for problems that are not currently present. We have a simple A-B problem, C hasn't even been created but we are already worrying about `what-ifs`. If there is another class C, we can rethink whether the method we want to call truly belongs in C, if it does, we can initialize C in A&call the method, otherwise we are just worrying about non-existent problems in the present 

Comment: But "when B extends A" looks pretty wrong. OOP should not work like that. You pass around instantiated objects, and you do not randomly extend classes to gain access to their methods

Comment: Again, assuming A and B are related, you are allowed to extend `A` as a base, instead of rewriting all the functionality into B. My solution was written on the premise that this relationship is between a base class A and an extension of A, `B`. There's no context or basis for stating that this is just a random extension, we both cannot know that because we are not in the context of the person writing this code.

Comment: I offered a probable solution, there are many different ways to do this but to state with so much certainty that one is wrong over the other isn't great for anyone reading this. Context is very important, try to consider that.